# How do I let users Beta Test my iOS app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

I have my .mobileProvision and my cert generated using openssl. I have the .ipa file. I hit iOS Deployment Type = Apple App Store so that others could install it. One of my workers in my group is unable to run it on her iPhone.

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RrSNbGwWunY/WJgRKvOSsqI/AAAAAAAAAAs/yGjWSgT7AZsTxfM6Tw4CQFy7k6e02K_HgCK8B/s512/2017-02-05.jpg]

I am using Adobe Animate to export it. I have a developer through apple. With Android, it's as simple as typing in the password for the cert and handing the .apk file over. Then telling them to go to their android settings and tap "Allow apps from 3rd party developers"

Comment: Please use Cmd+Shift+4 to take screenshots on mac.

Comment: It was from a beta tester haha I understand your concern though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities :

- Use TestFlight to invite users downloading your app before release (the procedure is well explained by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/))
- Manually install the app on tester's iPhone thanks to Xcode (just Run the app on it)
- Use third party services such as [Installr](https://www.installrapp.com/) which allow you to easily install your app on testers' iPhone (up to 3 device with free version)

I think Deployment Type should be something like Ad-Hoc version and not Apple App Store.

Comment: I have never touched iTunes in my life. It looks like the management for TestFlight is done there. Can this all be done on windows?

Comment: iTunes is available on Windows, so you can give it a try. But generally speaking, iOS development is made for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use adhoc so they can install over wifi and i use test fairy instead of testflight.

U still have to get their udid unless u have an enterprise account